# Expression engine showing garbage content while using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine, php-5.3

Expressionengine is showing garbage value when I am using php for Json encode its showing this content {!-- ra:0000000019930c5000007efd6bf7e0f5 --}

here is my code :-

```
<?php

$entries = array();
{exp:channel:entries channel="sport" category="3536|1830|4102" site="default_site" limit="3"  track_views="one" dynamic="no" status="open|featured" disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data" terminate="yes"}
   $entries[] = array('title' => '{title}');
{/exp:channel:entries}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($entries);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah ! finally I got the answer its so simple here is the solution :-

go to ExpressionEngine\system\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Template\Annotation\Runtime.php

on line no. 65 comment the code `return '{!-- ra:'.$key.' --}';`

Comment: To anyone who find this answer, this is a really bad practice to modify the core ExpressionEngine code.

Comment: @Link14 I don't think so because if core files has errors then we have to fix it.Core files are not developed by GOD those are also developers they did mistake we should resolve it.

Comment: True, you do whatever you need to do to make things work. But modifying the core files is still a bad practice. Not because some god wrote those files, but because I believe a CMS should be treated as a dependency, not as a part of your project. Moreover, it can be hard to keep track of those kind of changes. And when you update the CMS, you will probably forgot to put your change in again, or might have a hard time finding where to insert your change because files can change a lot. In this case, this isn't even a bug. The 2 first answers clearly explain what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

If you see this kind of garbage value on the page that means the page has an error.
We mostly find this garbage value on PHP-enabled templates. So if we resolve the PHP errors the garbage will go.
Do not modify the ExpressionEngine core files. If you want to see the PHP errors on the page, turn on the debug mode.

If you remove the `exit()` function, you will get the output as you want.
The `exit()` function also exits the execution of ExpressionEngine code that's why you are getting the garbage value.

Comment: No there was not any syntax error. may be caching issue but not sure about it.

Comment: Hi @RaviSharma , I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler - remove the `exit()`.

As [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34778/php-template-shows-code-in) explains, these are annotation tags used for debugging (so you can get a stack trace for nested templates I suppose) and they are parsed out late in the process. So if you exit() it doesn't work. Just make sure that the script ends with no unwanted output and you should be good. I had this problem (in EEv5) and this was the fix.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same style of error codes appear, when moving an old EE 2.9.3 site to a Dev server and applying a test domain name.
There were some PHP Includes in the templates, which referenced the live site's server path. When I changed these... all fixed.

For example:
include("/home/sites/domainname.co.uk/public_html/swift/swift_required.php");
...changed to...
include("/home/domain/public_html/swift/swift_required.php");